# Switching on Union types in Flow

Tags: react-native, flowtype

This code uses `field.type` which is a string to determine what component to render.

The `SelectOptionsOverlay` component will render a `CardFormSelectField` (`type=="select"`) with its `options`.

`CardFormTextAreaOverlay` will render a `CardFormTextAreaField` (`type=="textarea"`), and this component will never try to use `options` or any other property not present in `CardFormTextAreaField`.

```js
export type CardFormSelectField = {
  title: string,
  type: string,
  placeholder: string,
  options: string[]
};

export type CardFormTextAreaField = {
  title: string,
  type: string
};

export type CardFormField = CardFormSelectField | CardFormTextAreaField;

overlay(field: CardFormField): ?(SelectOptionsOverlay | CardFormTextAreaOverlay) {
    const props = {...};
    switch (field.type) {
      case "select":
        return <SelectOptionsOverlay {...props} />;
      case "textarea":
        return <CardFormTextAreaOverlay {...props} />;
    }
  }
```

The `switch` statement keeps this all safe. However, Flow doesn't "know about" the switch statement and its safety benefits, so it complains:

```
Cannot return <SelectOptionsOverlay /> because: 
Either React.Element [1] is incompatible with SelectOptionsOverlay [2].
Or React.Element [1] is incompatible with CardFormTextAreaOverlay [2].
```

`[1]` is the return statement and `[2]` is the type declaration for the function's return value: `?(SelectOptionsOverlay | CardFormTextAreaOverlay)`

There is also a corresponding error on the second return statement (for `CardFormTextAreaOverlay`).

I'm actually having trouble understanding what this means, let alone if it's possible to fix it.

On the other hand, which I understand much better, if I remove the type annotation for the return statement, Flow only complains on the return statement with `SelectOptionsOverlay`, complaining about how the `field` prop may contain `options` and `placeholder` which is not present in `CardFormTextAreaField`.

That's true, but the switch statement should protect us from having bad props in our actual return. But you can't switch on FlowType can you? Since Flow isn't actual JS?

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible and makes sense for your code, you can specialize the `type` property for each `CardFormField`. For example, instead of `type: string` for `CardFormSelectField`, you could have `type: "select"`. This way, Flow knows that when it enters the `case "select"` block, `props` must be of the type `CardFormSelectField`. Currently, there is no way for Flow to associate each `case` statement with a specific type in the union type.

```
import React from 'react';

type CardFormSelectField = {|
  title: string,
  type: "select", // NEW!
  placeholder: string,
  options: string[]
|};

type CardFormTextAreaField = {|
  title: string,
  type: "textarea", // NEW!
|};

type CardFormField = CardFormSelectField | CardFormTextAreaField;

function SelectOptionsOverlay(props: CardFormSelectField) {
  return "SelectOptionsOverlay";
}

function CardFormTextAreaOverlay(props: CardFormTextAreaField) {
  return "CardFormTextAreaOverlay";
}

function Overlay(props: CardFormField) {
  switch (props.type) {
    case "select":
      (props: CardFormSelectField);
      return <SelectOptionsOverlay {...props} />;
    case "textarea":
      (props: CardFormTextAreaField);
      return <CardFormTextAreaOverlay {...props} />;
  }
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgGEUoATAMWhAGUkAbJDG2B8WcALxwA3gB9ycODGAx+ALjgBnGFGAA7AOYAaOQtpI1AInV8BMcwbgB6B3AByAUQDqAQmNhe6JAALCF4WJCg1TW19I3kIMEUIHXVIrV09AG0AXXJpAF8KKlNGZnZOABUkAA8YAEEiFCERcSlZeUVlMw00mOMaOgsYaphmVDtHZ3dvXILKfvomVg4oECbQlsWylZ5+QWF16RKliuH61DWWQswAVx0MYCS4HZsAeQSH5JeAN3D-agAKMA4MApI5bbjWPYiACUUmMRBg1ygOjg5meGDeiU+Pygf3MFDylBudyxYOWIEqNTOKG+vxQAKB8VBm3JlLqDQusMk8KQiORqJZJypDVpuPp+PIhPIxPuj1Ff0BwOZpXJnLh8nUAHclGhAnBFUyAHTzLnGeRoFBWVFWXa2FRm+T6xkgtSC7aQmCciiOx0IpEogA86JgmI+6nl9KkhujzvUeUcAD5vY6LVbzEMaqMUOZ7T75AaXWShezzvsWNDkz6-fyA26KacRTi-lGY0r4w4k8ZCXkgA)